# Custom header layout for React Native

Tags: layout, react-native, flexbox

Trying to construct a header in react-native. I have managed to get this far but I wanted to have the header centered and the right text right-aligned. Is there any simple combination using flexbox to achieve this?

```
   <View style={{marginTop: 20, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
       <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20, borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>Left with long text</Text>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>Title</Text>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>Right</Text>
       </View>
    </View>
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'I wanted to have the header centered' ?

Comment: `textAlign: 'right'` would fix the "Right" text. How is it not centered now?

Comment: Any picture of how do you want the header looks like?

Comment: Btw, the `justifyContent:'center',` might override the `textAlign` for the 3rd item, so in case of keeping `justifyContent`, make it `justifyContent:'flex-end',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you issue correctly this code will solve your problem:

```
      <View style={{paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 20, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1}}>Left with long sd asdf text</Text>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1, textAlign: 'center'}}>Title</Text>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, borderColor:'red', borderWidth:1, textAlign: 'right'}}>Right</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

for this situation, you can use react-native-falt-header library. this lib support all of your need for the center, left and right text and button handlers.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flat-header

example:

```js
<FlatHeader
    leftIcon={<Icon name="arrow-left" size={30} color="#FFF" />}
    leftText="back"
    leftContentHandler={() => {
        console.warn('Left both icon and text pressed');
    }}
    centerContent={
        <Group>
            <Icon name="comment" size={30} color="#FFF" />
            <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>FAQ</Text>
        </Group>
    }
    rightIcon={<Icon name="star" size={30} color="#FFF" />}
    style={{ marginTop: 20, backgroundColor:'yellow' }}
    />
```

Comment: You should probably disclose that you own/run this library.